# Mix and Match Avocent IPKVM with APC Server Module?

Tags: keyboard-video-mouse

We have an Avocent DSR 1030 not currently being used and a good number of APC CAT5/IP KVM Server Modules. These say they are for an APC AP 5460, however, is there anything special about the APC modules that require them to be paired with APC gear, or could they be used along with the Avocent?

Comment: Very unlikely.  The modules are usually proprietary, even though many vendors just rebrand Avocent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very unlikely. The modules are usually proprietary, even though many vendors just rebrand Avocent products.